# How to sum value in specific column of data in datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have list of data from database which contain sales data.I display them in dataTable format where everything works fine.I need to have the sum in two of my column in a tfoot (footer) but sum don't display.
I am try to get a sum of each column and display the result in the footer. I'm using "footerCallback" function that Datatables provides. However it is not displaying anything in the footer

My java script codes

```
if(!empty($report)){
  if($report->num_rows()>0){?>
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Created at</th>
        <th>Shop</th>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Unit Price</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php
      foreach($report->result() as $s){
        $page++;
        ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $page; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo date('d/m/Y',strtotime($s->sales_date)); ?></td>
          <td><?php echo date('d/m/Y',strtotime($s->created_at)); ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $s->shop_name; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $s->product_name; ?></td>
          <td>
            <?php if($s->sales_type==0)
                      echo"Wholesale";
                  else
                      echo"Retail";?>
          </td>
          <td><?php echo number_format($s->unit_price); ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $s->qty; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo number_format($s->price); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
      }
      ?>
    </tbody>
     <tfoot>
     <tr>
        <th colspan="7">Total</th> 
        <th></th> 
        <th></th> 
        </tr>
     </tfoot>
  </table>
<div class="pagination"><?php echo $links; ?></div>
<div class="form-group">
    <a href="<?=base_url();?>user/printrangereport/<?=$startdate;?>/<?=$enddate;?>/<?=$theshop;?>/<?=$theproduct;?>" class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank">PRINT</a>
 </div>
<?php }
else{
  ?>
<div class="errors" role="alert">
  No Information was Found.
  <span class="closebtn pull-right" style="float: right;" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span></div>
  <?php
}}?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dataTable').DataTable( {
        searching: true, 
        responsive: false, 
        paging: false,
        pageLength: 10,
        dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-8'B><'col-sm-4'f>>tp", 
        buttons: [  
            {extend: 'copy', className: 'btn-sm', footer: true}, 
            {extend: 'csv', title: 'ExampleFile', className: 'btn-sm', footer: true}, 
            {extend: 'excel', title: 'ExampleFile', className: 'btn-sm', footer: true, title: 'exportTitle'}, 
            {extend: 'pdf', title: 'ExampleFile', className: 'btn-sm', footer: true}, 
            {extend: 'print', className: 'btn-sm', footer: true} 
        ],
        "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
            var api = this.api(), data;
            var intVal = function (i) {
                return typeof i === 'string' ? i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1:typeof i === 'number' ? i : 0;
            };  
            //#----------- Total over this page------------------#
           
            qtyTotal = api.column(7, { page: 'current'} ).data().reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                },0);  
            priceTotal = api.column(8, { page: 'current'} ).data().reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                },0); 
            //#-----------ends of Total over this page------------------#

            // Update footer
            $( api.column(7).footer()).html(qtyTotal);
            $( api.column(8).footer()).html(priceTotal);
        }
    } );
} );
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide the rendered HTML, we shouldn't have to make assumptions about the content of the page. -> [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: As you're asking about jquery and tagged [tag:html], please remove the php parts as they don't appear to be relevant and it means we (though should be you) can't create a [mcve].

Comment: Did you debug what `qtyTotal` and `priceTotal` were before attempting to update the footer?

Answer (score -1):

Long back I used this function maybe it will help you.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        
        "columnDefs": [
              { className: "crdr", "targets": [4] }
            ],
        
        "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
            var api = this.api(), data;
 
            // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
            var intVal = function ( i ) {
                return typeof i === 'string' ?
                    i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
                    typeof i === 'number' ?
                        i : 0;
            };
 
            // Total over all pages
            total = api
                .column( 4 )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                } );
 
            // Total over this page
            pageTotal = api
                .column( 4, { page: 'current'} )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );
 
            // Update footer
            $( api.column( 4 ).footer() ).html(
                '$'+pageTotal +' ( $'+ total +' total)'
            );
        }
    } );
} );
```

here is working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Negirox/cL5erjxq/)